# Delayed job on rails, how to know when it is processed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, paperclip, delayed-job

Currently I'm working with delayed_job to process pdf files and I need to know if a file has been processed.

Once completed I need to change a value in the database to notify the user that their file has been processed correctly.

I'm using delayed_job with mongoid and paperclip as processor.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by processing pdf files?

Comment: You described exactly what you need to do in your question. Where are you getting lost?

Comment: Check my last answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried this callback and it works:

```
# config/intializers/delayed_paperclip
    module DelayedPaperclip
      module Jobs
        class DelayedJob

          def success
            # here comes database change value
          end

        end
      end
    end
```

But the problem is that I can't refer to the parent of this job to get the object id and change the database value to processed = true.

This is the job object, without parent reference:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53f504e06d696e5fc5010000"),
    "priority" : 0,
    "attempts" : 0,
    "queue" : null,
    "handler" : "--- !ruby/struct:DelayedPaperclip::Jobs::DelayedJob\ninstance_klass: Note\ninstance_id: !ruby/object:BSON::ObjectId\n  raw_data: !binary |-\n    U/UE321pbl/FAAAA\nattachment_name: :file\n",
    "run_at" : ISODate("2014-08-20T20:28:16.178Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2014-08-20T20:28:16.178Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2014-08-20T20:28:16.178Z")
}
```

How Can I refer to the creator of the job?

Is there any other solution? (obviously yes, I suppose)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply define a method which first processes the pdf and then changes the database values or notifies a user and run that as the delayed job.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem lately, although my code was using different convention of job execution. Instead of using Job class it uses delay method e.g. myobj.report.delay.generate_downloaded_version

all you need is hidden in handler in such case because myobj is being serialized to YAML, therefore:

```
irb(main):018:0> job = Delayed::Job.find("53c64778bd19836c5f00009b")
irb(main):020:0> YAML::load(job.handler)
=> #<Delayed::PerformableMethod:0x7f6a569d4230 @object=#<Analysis::Report _id: 53b161c2bd198338cb000030, analysis_id: BSON::ObjectId('53b143f4bd19835c96000016'), created_at: Mon Jun 30 13:10:26 UTC 2014, updated_at: Wed Jul 16 12:31:11 UTC 2014, validator_ids: ["links"], page_patern: "*", _type: nil, pages: nil, entries: [], report_type: "detail", message_levels: ["errors", "warnings"], locale: "pl", state: "enqueued">, @args=[], @method_name=:generate_downloaded_version>
irb(main):021:0>
```